# Can you use functions from an imported standalone script as cell formula custom functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have imported a standalone Google App Script project (called `SheetUtilities`) that has basic library functions into another Google Sheet document (`SheetTest`). I want to use the functions from `SheetUtilities` as custom functions in cell formulas in `SheetTest`.

I can successfully call the functions in the script editor in `SheetTest` for example:

```
function wrapperfunc(){
  SheetUtilities.foo();
}
```

However, if go into a cell and call `=foo()` or `=SheetUtilities.foo()` I get a `#NAME?` error. How can I make these imported library functions available in the target sheet document? I would like this library to be useable across all my sheets.

I know this is possible using Sheets Addons, for example the `Date Add Subtract` add on from Google adds a couple new cell functions. However I don't want to have to publish an add on to get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can - but there's some trickery involved. Also, I'm not considering the scenario where the source script and the imported library target different scopes. Please note that custom functions are quite limited in terms of what they can do and can't access many advanced services.

With custom functions, you can only target global scope. Also, your SheetUtilities object is not a function, although, technically speaking, everything is an object in JavaScript.

To sum up, it seems that, from a spreadsheet cell, you can only reference the type of "objects" that are 1) located in global scope 2) inherit from Function.prototype

The only solution I can think of is to write the function specifically for the purpose of invoking nested functions inside libraries. As the first argument, we'll pass the string in the following format

> "LIBNAME.FUNCNAME"

followed by the list of arguments for the function itself.

```
function CALL_LIB(libDotFunc){

  var arr = libDotFunc.split("."); //a string to array with "." as separator
  var lib = arr[0]; //getting library name
  var func = arr[1]; //getting function name
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //convert arguments object to an array
  var params = args.slice(1); //this will return any other arguments passed to the function

  return this[lib][func].apply(this, params);

}
```

The library is simply the property of the global object that the first 'this' points to. Conversely, the nested function is one of the properties of the library object.

```
this[lib][func] //selecting the function to be executed
```

Finally, we call the function passing the required parameters. At this stage, we must have the 'this' object point to the function itself (the variable to the left of the dot).

```
return this[lib][func].apply(this, params);
```

You may then call library functions from a cell like this

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks. How is it that an add-on can add functions that can be called directly, but a script cannot? Does it come down to different permissioning?

Comment: @rkp333 Not sure what you mean by calling functions directly. The addon-on you mentioned doesn't rely on any external libraries. https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/tree/master/sheets/dateAddAndSubtract   If you examine the code, it consists of 2 *.gs files, both of which are in global scope. Unlike Node.js where each file is a separate module, in GAS the namespace is shared between files in a single project. Because everything is in global scope, you can easily reference DATE functions from Spreadsheet cells. Add-ons are basically just standalone scripts meant for distribution.

Comment: @rkp333 Also, if the solution works for you, please consider marking the question as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I was expecting that importing a stand along script made it a part of the project, and its functions part of the global scope of the importing sheet, just like adding an addon seems to do. But this is not the case.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found to date.